# Ubuntu 20.04 issue wirh hibernation

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, hibernate

I am having an issue with hibernate mode. It occurs when I have a lot of items opened in my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE) and I choose 'hibernate'.

After coming back into wake mode, the OS  reboots, and I have clean desktop like I would have if I had clicked '*restart*' option.

What can I do to have all running applications saved when using hibernation?

Comment: Do you have `swap` slightly larger than RAM? `free` will tell you. Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Are you still having this issue?I styled the Q a bit. Hopefully it will help get an answer. The extra tags usually mean more eyes on the question.

Comment: hello, 
so sorry for my delay.
Yes, I resolved my issue - I have 16G of RAM and I had only 4G of SWAP and that was the problem.
BTW. what do You mean to edit ?